# Error in JTable not working

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, nullpointerexception, jtable

I am trying to extract some data from table and then adding them into JTable but however it is giving me an exception. 
Please check if some thing is wrong -

```
final String[] columns = {"Messages","Status"};
final Object[][] data = new Object[100][];

try
{

PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement("select Message,status from mesaages12 where Sender = ?");
p.setInt(1,empid);
r8 = p.executeQuery();
int k = 0;

    while(r8.next())
    {

            data[k] = new String[1000];
            data[k][0] = r8.getString(1);
        if(String.valueAt(r8.getInt()).equals(null))
            data[k][1] = "0"
        else
            data[k][1] = String.valueOf(r8.getInt(2));
            k++;

    }
}

p.close();

}

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

final JTable table = new JTable(data,columns);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
scroll.setBounds(100,250,500,300);
f9.add(scroll);
```

I dont what i am doing wrong.

structure of table is -

```
Message  status  Sender
text     number  number
```

Please tell me what mistake i have done?

```
java.sql.SQLException: No data found
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7145)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataInteger(JdbcOdbc.java:3818)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataInteger(JdbcOdbcResultSet.jav
:5637)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:582)
        at ntpc.Sms$1$5.actionPerformed(Sms.java:997)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2
18)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.ja
a:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonMode
.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:25
)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButton
istener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:483
)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492

        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD
main.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD
main.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThr
ad.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread
java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThr
ad.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:690)
        at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
        at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5719)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114

        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:201
)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
        at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5226)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintM
nager.java:1529)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:14
2)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
        at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39

        at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java
78)
        at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:1
5)
        at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
        at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:819)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD
main.java:76)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796

        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769

        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:
18)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.jav
:1677)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThr
ad.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread
java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThr
ad.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:690)
        at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
        at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5719)
```

Comment: can you share us the exception.

Comment: it is java NULL Pointer Exception

Comment: The stacktrace points out the exact line number which caused the exception. You may examine the line.

Comment: share complete code along with the stack trace and exact line number.

Comment: it contains data i have checked manually

Comment: this line `String.valueOf(r8.getInt(2));` might result in exception if status is `null`

Comment: if(String.valueOf(r8.getInt(2)).equals(null))
           data[k][1] = "0";
          else
           data[k][1] = String.valueOf(r8.getInt(2));

Comment: still the problem exist

Comment: simply use `r8.getString(2)` instead of `String.valueOf(r8.getInt(2))`

Comment: the field is number and not text

Comment: thank u all its solved using r8.getString(2)

Answer (score 0):

> what i am doing wrong?

- calling `r8.next()` multiple times can cause the issue.
- remove `if(r8.next())` from outside and inside the `while` loop.
- use `List` instead of static array if the size it not known in advance.

Sample code:

```
final String[] columns = { "Messages", "Status" };
final List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();


    ...
    ResultSet r8 = p.executeQuery();
    while (r8.next()) {
        Object[] array = new Object[2];
        ...
        data.add(array);
    }
    ...

final JTable table = new JTable(data.toArray(new Object[][] {}), columns);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
```

---

#### EDIT

the problem is at below line where if status is `null`

```
String.valueOf(r8.getInt(2));
```

Simply use `r8.getString(2)` instead of `String.valueOf(r8.getInt(2))`

Comment: there is a problem with JTable i removed while(r8.next()) to while(true)

Comment: I am not saying to change it to `while(true)` just remove extra `if` check on next record.

Comment: major of reasons for why we are always asked for an SSCCE/MCVE :-)